# item with existing key, when creating MappingConfiguration

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

```
public class ClinicController
{
    private List<Employee> Employees;
    private List<Patient> Patients;
    private Mapper _objectMapper;

    public ClinicController()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
        Patients = new List<Patient>();
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Doctor, DoctorDto>().ReverseMap();
            //cfg.CreateMap<Employee, Doctor>();
            //cfg.CreateMap<DoctorDto, Doctor>();
            //cfg.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>();
            //cfg.CreateMap<Patient, DoctorDto>();
        });
        _objectMapper = new Mapper(config);
    }
}
```

When I instantiate this class, whenever config is created, an Exception is raised. It says:

```
"An item with the same key has already been added"
```

I have been reading questions with the same issue, and I cannot seem to figure out the issue. Debugging the code has revealed that the program never gets to initialize the Mapper, it crashes right before, when config is initialized.

What have I overlooked?

Classes:

```
public abstract class PersonDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surnames { get; set; }
    public string Data{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
}
public abstract class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surnames { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
}
public class Patient : Person
    {
        public string Service { get; set; }
        public float Pay { get; set; }
    }
    public class Employee : Person
    {
        public string Job { get; set; }
        public float Salary { get; set; }
    }
public class Doctor : Employee
{
    public new string Job = "Doctor";
}
```

This are classes with the same properties as the originals ( i haven't included the methods, since they're irrelevant). The Dtos follow the same structure as the entities themselves.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9SHxcs). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @John you just need to create a new instance of the class. I understand thatyou also need the classes used in the mapping, however I am not allowed to share that code.

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to share it? Surely you can create a completely unrelated mock ups with the same data types, but without any meaningful names, etc.? Either way, without a reproduction case we can't help you.

Comment: [Still can't reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9SHxcs).

Comment: Acording to my Senior, I cannot share any kind of code related to the database Models. That seems Includes the classes used here(as they are Entities used in EF), and their respective dtos

Comment: So if you have a class with a property like `public string PatientId {get;set;}`, you can't change it to `public string PropertyA {get;set;}`, etc.? Without an actual reproduction case we can't help you because we can't reproduce the scenario. I'd recommend talking to your manager and ask if you can share a anonymized version of the class so that you can work through this problem, or ask your manager to help you fix it. Alternatively, create a new application with two classes, and try to figure out what is specifically causing the issue yourself.

Comment: Then, even if you're not able to fix it yourself, you'll be able to give us enough information to help you. And if it's completely new test classes, perhaps your manager will even let you share them?

Comment: @John The scenario you described is correct. I'll talk with my senior.

Comment: I added some anonymized classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Doctor DTO also has "overwritten" the Job property, it will crash since there'll be 2 Job "Keys". Don't use new string and find another way to do it. 
Sine you're mapping Doctors to their DTOs there should be no need to specify the Job's value (assuming it's not modified and stored in the DB).

Comment: Just tested it. It works, i didn't even think about how useless it is to have that Job definition on the DTO. Thanks